# Can you run an outside CLI command inside of a CLI you're developing?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm developing a CLI that needs to generate angular components as well as 
creating other files in a separate module. So, the project that the CLI will assist in would ideally call `ng generate` to handle the angular side of things, and then use fs-extra to go into the other module and add files. It's for a CMS SPA editor where the angular code and CMS code live in the same project.

So, am I able to run a different CLI's commands inside of my node CLI that I'm developing, or do I need to manually create all the files that `ng generate` is going to create along with the other files I'm creating at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you expand on your question? When you say you are `developing a CLI` are you saying you are `creating an application using the Angular CLI`? If so, then yes. Once you create an application you can continue to use the CLI to generate the pieces of the application. If you mean something else, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @DeborahK I updated my question to be more clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular Schematics are the smarts behind the Angular CLI. You can use the schematics to build your own CLI leveraging the features of Angular Schematics. That way you will still get all of the `ng generate` functionality.

See these articles for more information on the CLI schematics:

https://brianflove.com/2018/12/11/angular-schematics-tutorial/

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is what I need.